# How to post HTML code on Codepen by making a post reqest

Tags: html, api, post, codepen

I am trying to generate a url wherein I can get my HTML code on my application to open in codepen so the user can edit the same. Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Try this article - https://codepen.io/guuslieben/post/codepen-api-v2 and this site - https://cpv2api.com/ (An unofficial, public JSON API for CodePen)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.